# Add progressive shipping costs by product in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, shipping-method

I want to put shipping cost based on by product.

for example I have 2x $2 shampoo, and 1 x $4 soap, and my shipping cost was 4$, then it will be like this.

```
-------------------------------------------------
2 shampoo x 2$ + 4$ shipping cost  = 8$
1 soap    x $4 + 4$ shipping cost  = 8$
-------------------------------------------------
                             total = 16$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just about settings in Woocommerce Settings > Shipping:

1. You will add and use as many shipping classes than products with different shipping rates.
2. For each shipping zone you will have to add a Flat rate shipping method.

   - For "shampoo" in the related shipping class you will add the following: **`4+([qty]*2)`**
   - For "Soap" in the related shipping class you will add the following: **`4+([qty]*4)`**
   - … You will do that for each created needed shipping class…
   - For the **"No shipping class cost"** you will set your default rate like for example: **`4+[qty]`**
   - You will choose option: "Per class: Charge shipping for each shipping class individually".

   [image]

In your products you will select the correct shipping class in Product data metabox > Shipping:

[image]

Now everything will work as you want.